# Smart cropping of images and add border

Tags: automator, graphics, image-editing, crop

I need to perform batch cropping to approximately 3000 images. Each image is for a different item.

What I need is a crop tool that can define the item from the background and add specific amount of pixels to the top, bottom, right and left of it.

For example, see the image below. Can I use Automator?

[image]

Comment: Due to the sheer complexity, I think this probably falls outside the scope of what's easy with Automator. I'd look into writing a more complete program or utilizing something that already exits.

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought but i can not find any software that can do that.

Comment: Python, Java, and most other languages should have libraries available to handle images. It's really up to you. I just think this is probably outside of what Automator can do easily: it might be possible to use shell scripts to do this with added libraries.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org), available on [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

```
convert /path/to/in.png \
  -trim \
  +repage \
  -bordercolor White \
  -border 100x100 \
  /path/to/out.png
```

1. The image is trimmed using [`-trim`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) operation which removes the border from the image.

   > This option removes any edges that are exactly the same color as the corner pixels. Use -fuzz to make -trim remove edges that are nearly the same color as the corner pixels.

   <sup>http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php</sup>
2. A [`+repage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#repage) is performed on the virtual canvas to ‘flatten’ the crop.
3. The [`-border`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#border) is added, in [White](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#bordercolor).